# Next JS nextjs rewrites not working as intended

Tags: next.js

I am proxying part of my site to a 'new' nextjs page, as such all my assets, images etc... are messing up because the pathing is wrong.

So, I used "assetPrefix" for the css/js files, BUT all my images and api's are wrong, so I am trying to do a rewrite and its not working...

Is there a way to have next be able to ignore the host (that is proxing) and just use its own domain.. for instance, all the assets are: https://preview.mysite.com (current site), but I want it to use its "real domain" -- https://previewnext.mysite.com

```
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: 'https://preview.mysite.com/_next/image*',
        destination: 'https://previewnext.mysite.com/_next/image*'
      },
```

basically, if the path is: https://preview.mysite.com/_next/image?, which is my current domain that proxies the nextjs site, SO I need the nextjs site to actually rewrite those image assets to: https://previewnext.mysite.com/_next/image*

Seems a huge limitation to not be able to use absolute paths for rewrites.

Comment: got any solution for this ?

Comment: no, some of them I got working with assetPrefix in the config, the others i had to use a proxy for the rewrites. Next is great, but it has some glaring issues... and they seem to be more focused on the low hanging fruit for wins. Marketing.